# Magento 2.1.2, Remove "region" from the Address

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-address, address, billing-address

I would like to remove "**Region**" from all the address forms (`checkout, billing address, shipping address, customer's addressbook`). 
I've set the Backend setting for "Allow to Choose State if It is Optional for Country" to No (under `Stores > Configuration > General > General, State Options`), but the State Option still gets displayed on the Frontend, but is disabled.

What would be the the right way to remove region option from the **address forms**?

---

If I update the Backend settings to:

**State is Required for**: remove all selected country from here.

**Allow to Choose State if It is Optional for Country**: Set it as "No"

does not **remove** the Region (Bundesland/Provinz) on the forms, it only disables it.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want disable **Region** from the address, you have to set below option like.

**State is Required for :** remove all selected country from here.

**Allow to Choose State if It is Optional for Country :** Set it as "**No**"

You can also remove it from "add new address" in customer account.

Copy file form `vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/address/edit.phtml`

add it in your theme. You can remove **region** from here for customer add new address.

Save configuration, remove var folder.

Comment: If I unset all options for the "State is Required for" and save it, the options do not get saved. @S H Patel can you save "no values" for this attribute?

Comment: it required any one country, you can select any one country which is not use for store.

Comment: This does not **remove** the region option on the frontend, but it only disables it.

Comment: You mean required false ?

Comment: Following your instructions would make the "region" field not required, but the field would still be displayed on the frontend. My question was how to remove the field, meaning it would not be displayed on the frontend.

Comment: If you set "Allow to Choose State if It is Optional for Country" : Set it as "No", region field will not display on front.

Comment: I have tried the settings you've suggested and the "Region" is still visible on the Frontend, it is only disabled. I'm working with Magento 2.1.2.

Comment: Remove var folder, delete browser cache and check again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48929/discussion-between-s-h-patel-and-knospe).

Comment: The region is still present in the "add new address to the address book" address form.

Comment: I have updated my answer. kindly check it.

Comment: How it can be removed only in Estimate and Shipping tax in section of cart page?

Answer (score 1):

You can hide country and region inside your plugins app/code/company/Magento_Theme/Plugin/Checkout/Block/LayoutProcessor.php

This does not remove it but makes it invisible so close enough from a users point of view for checkout.

```
$jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset'] 
['children']['country_id']['visible'] = false;


$jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children'] 
['region']['visible'] = false; // I think it's region...
```

Or could modify it in the DB possibly, but some of the forms for customer addressbook are still hard coded in template theme. Search in files for the label, make a copy of it as needed in your theme and make it style="display: none;" ?

Urgh.... why...

Can also say State is Required for and uncheck the country in the Store COnfig

https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/removedisable-magento-2-state-option/

> To set up the state options in Magento 2 you need to follow these steps:
>
> On the Admin sidebar, tap Stores. Then under Settings, choose Configuration. In the panel on the left under General, choose General.
>
> Expand the State Options section, and do the following:
>
> a, In the State is required for list, select each country where Region/State is > a required entry.
>
> b, Set the Allow to Choose State if it is Optional for Country field to one of > the following:
>
> Yes In countries where the state field is not required, includes the State > field as an optional entry.
>   No In countries where the state field is not required, omits the State field.
>   When complete, tap Save Config .